# Can i make my date range code more efficient by using a loop?

Tags: pandas

I created a SQL database of my financial transactions. I wish to create dataframes in python and pandas that sum my spending by month. I have created the below code which works. But wish to make it more efficient. How could this be done?

code sample.

```
jan_spend = df[df['date'].between('2022-01-01', '2022-01-31')]
jan_spend_df = jan_spend[['date', 'amount']]
jan_total = jan_spend_df['amount'].sum()


feb_spend = df[df['date'].between('2022-02-01', '2022-02-28')]
feb_spend_df = feb_spend[['date', 'amount']]
feb_total = feb_spend_df['amount'].sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a month column then group and sum rows with the same month.

```py
df['month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).apply(lambda x: '{year}-{month}'.format(year=x.year, month=x.month))
sum = df.groupby('month')['amount'].sum()
print(sum)
```

Result:

```
month
2022-1    1064
2022-2    1297
...
```